# How to make an Octave path root folder for all subfolders

Tags: octave

I have a folder for Octave M-files in `C:\\Users\Dropbox\Octave`, under which are various subfolders by function categories (normal distribution, chisq...). I just started making those subfolders and they will keep changing (adding, removing, reshuffling) as time goes on.

I would just like to set that folder as root and have Octave search for functions recursively there, just like you set a classpath in Java and JVM searches all folders there.

I used `addpath(genpath('C:\\Users\Dropbox\Octave'))`, but the paths generated are then fixed, not reflecting subsequent subfolder changes.

Shall I add `addpath(genpath('C:\\Users\Dropbox\Octave'))` to the `.octaverc` file?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to achieve dynamic path changes _within_ your session? Each time you start matlab/octave? Each time you run a particular script?

Comment: btw, note that octaverc is octave-specific (obviously). If you really _do_ care about matlab compatibility, make sure to point that out in your question explicitly, otherwise you're literally milliseconds away from the "ermagerd remove the matlabs" style comment here ...

Comment: I just care about octave. When I use addpath(genpath('..root folder')), I see that all subfolders are indeed added to paths but those paths don't change even I change the folder structure. I have now a A, B, C folders under Root, but I can add a D or remove B later. Those paths stay A, B ,C.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm leaving the matlab tag regardless, since I address matlab compatibility in my answer too.

Comment: ... aaaaaaaand it's gone.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is some confusion here. There are several ways to interact with the path, but for the most part these do not result in permanent changes, unless you save this somehow.

Simply adding a path for an existing octave session will not result in any permanent changes to the usual path that octave initialises at startup. Therefore when you say:

> I used addpath(genpath('C:\Users\Dropbox\Octave')), but the paths generated are then fixed, not reflecting subsequent subfolder changes.

this makes no sense, because as soon as you exit your octave session, those added paths should have been gone altogether, and not appear in later octave sessions.

It is more likely that at some point you added these paths, and then used the `savepath` command, which resulted in your custom paths being added to your `.octaverc` file.

If that is the case, then yes, you can expect that octave will not "update" what was written in your .octaverc file, unless you call `savepath` again with an updated path definition.

If you would like the `addpath(genpath('C:\Users\Dropbox\Octave'))` command you mentioned to be called every time octave starts, so that the current/updated directory structure is loaded, then yes, the best way to do it would be to add that command to your `.octaverc` file. Make sure you remove the lines in your .octaverc that refer to the previous changes made by `savepath`. Note that there may be several levels of octaverc files that you need to check (see the [relevant page in the manual](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Startup-Files.html))

Alternatively, you could simply make sure that this line appears in every script you want to call which intends to make use of those files.

While you may consider this last approach tedious, programmatically it is the most recommended one, since it makes dependencies clear in your code. This is especially important if you ever plan to share your code (and doubly so if you'd like it to be matlab compatible).

---

<sub>PS. All the above mostly applies to matlab too, with the exception that a) matlab's `savepath` saves path information in a file called `pathdef.m`, rather than directly in your startup files, and b) matlab uses `startup.m` instead of `.octaverc` as startup files. Also, if you don't care about doing this programmatically, matlab provides `pathtool`, which is a graphical interface for adding / saving directories to the matlab path.</sub>

Comment: yes, I called savepath after addpath(genpath('..root-folder')). I think adding that command directly to .octaverc will be best as I change the folder structure often.